# Libgdx restart the game when click on AdView

Tags: android, libgdx, admob

I have banner ad on my libgdx game and every time I click on the ad and then return to the game the game is restarted instead of being paused and then resume just like it happends when I click the "home buttom".

Here is how I add the adView to the libgdx game

```
    // adding adds
    layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    View gameView = initializeForView(game, configuration);
    adView = new AdView(this);

    // this is a test ad
    adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder()
            .build());

    // Add the AdMob view
    adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

    layout.addView(gameView);
    layout.addView(adView, adParams);

    // Hook it all up
    setContentView(layout);
```

Comment: Is this a low end device? Maybe resources got low so Android shut you down.

Comment: i don't think so.  I am using Samsung s5 mini and the game uses just 5 or less objects

Comment: yes you are right,  i restated my device and now it's working fine.  cheers